# Finding points of inflexion using second derivative

Tags: calculus

I am learning maths by self study. This is a problem I am trying to solve:

Find the range of values taken by the curve $y = \frac{12x}{(x^2 + 3)}$. Find also the coordinates of the points of inflexion of the curve.

I know that likely candidates for the points of inflexion are found where $f''(x) = 0$ or is undefined.

So I calculate $f'(x) = \frac{(-12x^2 + 36)}{(x^2 + 3)^2}$

Then I calculate $f''(x)$ as follows:

let u = $(-12x^2 + 36), v = (x^2 + 3)^2, \frac{du}{dx} = -24x, \frac{dv}{dx} = 4x^3 + 12x$

$f''(x) = \frac{v\frac{du}{dx} - u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2}$ which I get to be:

$\frac{2x^5 - x^4 -6x^2 - 18x-9}{24(x^2 +3)^4}$

The book gives the answers as (-3,-3),(0,0),(3,3) but although I can see that (0,0) is valid because it gives undefined I cannot see how the other values are obtained.

Obviously my working is wrong somewhere but I cannot see where.

Comment: Can you show your steps for when you expanded the numerator during the quotient rule?

Comment: Caution: the second derivative being undefined is not a *sufficient* condition. Consider $x(|x|+2x)$.

Comment: As the function is odd and has no singularities, the inflection point at the origin is obvious. Then it rejoins the $x$ axis on both sides and there must be two extra, symmetrical, inflections. By further reasoning, you can show that the numerator of the second derivative must be cubic (without computing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{12x}{x^2+3} \implies f''(x)=24\frac{x(x^2-9)}{(x^2+3)^3}=0\implies x=0,\pm 3.$$
So the point of imfexion are $x=0, \pm 3$, because at around these points the curve changes (convexity) the sign of it second darivative and the second derivative is zero at these points.

**Edit for OP:**
$$f'(x)=\frac{12 (x^2+3)-12x(2x)}{(x^2+3)^2}=\frac{-12(x^2-3)}{(x^2+3)^2}.$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{-12(2x)(x^2+3)^2+12(x^2-3)2(x^2+3)(2x)}{(x^2+3)^4}=\frac{24x^3-216x}{(x^2+3)^3}$$

Comment: You may see my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to carry the coefficient $12$, as the inflection condition is invariant to scaling.

The first derivative is
$$\left(\frac x{x^2+3}\right)'=\frac{x^2+3-x\cdot2x}{(x^2+3)^2}=\frac{-x^2+3}{(x^2+3)^2}.$$

Now it is enough to compute the numerator of the second derivative,

$$-2x(x^2+3)^2-(-x^2+3)2x\,2(x^2+3)=-2x(x^2+3)(x^2+3-2x^2+6)$$ and the roots $-3,0,3$ follow.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$f'(x)=-\frac{12 \left(x^2-3\right)}{\left(x^2+3\right)^2}\quad\text{and that}\quad f''(x)=\frac{24 x \left(x^2-9\right)}{\left(x^2+3\right)^3}.$$So, yes, $f''(x)=0\iff x=\pm3\text{ or }x=0$.

Comment: my problem is that I don't see how the second derivative follows from the first.

Comment: Because\begin{align}f''(x)&=-\frac{24x(x^2+3)^2-12(x^2-3)2x(x^2+3)}{(x^2+3)^4}\\&=-\frac{24x^3+24\times3x-48x^4+48\times3x}{(x^2+3)^3}\\&=\frac{24x^3-24\times9x}{(x^2+3)^2}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You have found $f'(x)$ correctly and your setup for the quotient rule is correct. However, you have expanded the brackets incorrectly:

$$\text{numerator} = (x^2+3)^2 (-24x) - (-12x^2+36)(4x^3+12x)$$
$$=(x^4+6x^2+9)(-24x)-(-12)(x^2-3)(2x)(2x^2+6)$$
$$=-24x(x^4+6x^2+9-(2x^4-18))$$
$$=-24x(x^4+4x^2-27)$$

and I'm sure you can factorise $x^4+4x^2-27$.

We can ignore the denominator $(x^2+3)^3$ as we can multiply both sides of $f''(x) = 0$ by the denominator, which gives us $\text{numerator} = 0$.
This is justified for all real numbers as $x^2+3 \ne 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, thus $(x^2+3)^3 \ne 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: You can factor *before* expanding the products.